# Unclear use of operator double()

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, implicit-conversion

I have a `Rectangle` class with conversion operators to both `double` and `std::string`:

```
class Rectangle
{
public:
    Rectangle(double x, double y) : _x(x), _y(y) {}
    operator std::string ();
    operator double ();
private:
    double _x, _y;
    double getArea() {return _x * _y;}
};

int main()
{
    Rectangle r(3, 2.5);
    cout << r << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I don’t understand why `operator double()` is invoked, rather than `operator std::string()`.
As far as I know, according to [C++ wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Programming/Operators/Operator_Overloading),
`operator double` is used to convert `Rectangle` objects to `double`.

So what's going on here?  Is it related to the fact that an `int` is passed to the constructor?  If so, why?

Comment: What does it even mean to convert a rectangle to a double.

Comment: i guess (double)r or somethig

Comment: @AlexGoft No, the other Alex meant “what does it mean *logically*?”. On the face of it, the operation seems meaningless.

Comment: I suspect he intended it to mean the area, since there is no other reason to have included the ``getArea()`` function in the sample.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You do not have an operator to output the rectangle to the stream.  `cout` does have an overload that takes a `double` and your class can be implicitly converted to a `double` so that is chosen.

The reason the string overload is not selected and is not considered as an ambiguity is because `operator <<` for a string is a member function and is not included in the [member overload](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt)  and [non member overload](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2) set of `cout`.  If we comment out the `operator double` we can see [we get a compiler error](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dc94121c3777cc7b).

If we want to have the `operator string` called then we would need to explicitly cast `r` into a string.  <kbd>[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a9e5be873d6c8813)</kbd>

Comment: Then why doesn't it pick the `string` conversion?

Comment: @interjay I was just looking into that.  I didn't see that operator when I wrote the answer,

Comment: Nice catch. If one wanted to explain why implementing `operator double()` on types that do not represent a number is a bad practice, he would be hard pressed to find a better illustration :-)

Comment: `std::ostream::operator<<(double)` is preferred over `std::basic_string::operator(basic_ostream&, const basic_string&)`

Comment: @SimonKraemer It's not that one is preferred over the other, it's that the other is simply never considered.

Answer (score 6):

Since you did not provide an `operator<<` overload for `Rectangle`, the compiler considers other overloads for which the arguments can be converted to the parameter types.

If any of the overloads are templates, then template argument substitution happens to them before overload resolution. The compiler tries to deduce the template parameters from the types of the arguments supplied to the function.

The `string` overload is not considered because of a **template argument substitution failure**:

```
template <class CharT, class Traits, class Allocator>
std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>&
    operator<<(std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& os,
               const std::basic_string<CharT, Traits, Allocator>& str);
```

Template argument substitution does not consider user-defined conversions, so the compiler can't deduce the types `CharT`, `Traits`, or `Allocator` from the type `Rectangle`, so this overload does not participate in overload resolution. (Recall that `std::string` is just a typedef of `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>`.)

Therefore there is one overload of `operator<<` which is a better match than any other, and that is the `double` overload. Not a template, but a member function of a class template.

```
basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>::operator<<(double);
```

Comment: Note that the last template is trivial; `std::cout` inherits from `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char>>`. There's no need for template argument substitution.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing special about double-overloading than other primitive types overloadings. In this case, it is the only primitive overload available.
The compiler will behave the same for int, char, etc..

Notice that if we would have more than one primitive type overload the compiler will throw

```
error: ambiguous overload for 'operator<<' ...
```