# ostream and operator std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>?

Tags: c++

from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32610625/6949852), I learned `std::string` is just typedef of `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>`, Template argument substitution does not consider user-defined conversions, so the compiler can't deduce the types CharT, Traits, or Allocator from the type Rectangle, so this overload does not participate in overload resolution.

Now I substitute std::basic_string, std::allocator> for std::string:

```
class Rectangle
{
public:
    Rectangle(double x, double y) : _x(x), _y(y) {}
    operator std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>> () {
        return std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>(to_string(_x) + " " + to_string(_y));
    }
    //operator double() {
    //  return _x;
    //}
private:
    double _x, _y;
    double getArea() { return _x * _y; }
};

int main()
{
    Rectangle r(3, 2.5);
    cout << r << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

---

It still fails. Why?

```
template <class CharT, class Traits, class Allocator>
std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& 
    operator<<(std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& os, 
               const std::basic_string<CharT, Traits, Allocator>& str);
```

Comment: you can define `std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& stream, const Rectangle& rectangle)` or use `cout << (string)r`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now I substitute std::basic_string, std::allocator> for std::string:
>   It still fails. Why?

You misunderstood the original problem. It wasn't because you used `std::string` instead of the direct `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>`. A typedef is just another name for an existing type. Your two conversion operators are exactly the same. You can verify that by trying to place them both in the class definition, it will cause a redefinition error.

Both aren't taken into account when resolving the overloads for `operator<<`, because conversions aren't applied to template function ordering.

Comment: Is there corresponding text in the standard? I tried to parse through overload resolution and templates, but couldn't find any.

Comment: @Incomputable - It's a combo of [\[temp.over\]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.over#1) and something in [\[temp.deduct\]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.deduct), which I'm having difficulty pinpointing at the moment.

Comment: @Incomputable - [Aha, it's paragraph 4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.deduct#call-4).

Comment: It's still completely non-obvious though :)

Comment: @Incomputable - Wouldn't be the C++ we know and love if it was obvious, would it? :)

Comment: Yeah, that's probably the gist of C++.  Thanks for finding the right part of the standard, perhaps I need to read it every evening.

Answer (score 2):

[Overload resolution](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution) *first* finds a set of possible functions to call. In this phase template deduction is performed to see if a template is a possible candidate.

Then, if more than one function is found, conversion functions are considered when trying to find the closest match among the candidates.

In your case, the operator taking a `std::string` is never considered as the compiler cannot deduce `CharT`etc from `Rectangle`.

---

A solution is to skip the conversion operator and instead add an `operator<<` for `Rectangle`. Inside that you can just call `os << to_string(...` etc.